# Web Scraping Atmospheric Data - Based on user input of date/time

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Trying to print atmospheric data based on user input of date/time. Date input used to append URL. The user then inputs "time" which points BS4 to the appropriate row and then data is stored from each column. For example, if the weather_time variable is between 3:00 - 3:59, the output will be the highlighted regions in the table, stored as unique variables.

[image]

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

print('What is the date (format 2018-09-18)?')
weather_date = input()
print('What time are you looking for?')
weather_time = input()

#connect to url
weather_url = 'https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/KTTD/date/' + weather_date
uClient = uReq(weather_url)
weather_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
weather_soup = soup(weather_html, "html.parser")
weather = weather_soup.findAll......
###magic####

temperature =
dew_point =
humidity =
pressure =
condition =

print('The weather on', + weather_date, 'at time', weather_time, 'was')
print('Temperature', + temperature)
print('Dew Point', + dew_point)
print('Humidity', + humidity)
print('Pressure', + pressure)
print('Condition', + condition)
```

Comment: What does it output ? What did you expect ?

Comment: nothing, can't figure out the appropriate code (see ###magic###) to get the data that's located in the table